# Problems with Trainer class CNTK

Tags: python, cntk

I have installed cntk, version 2.6 and I am trying to run the following script:

```
print("Before Trainer")
trainer = C.Trainer(model, (cross_entroy, error), [sgd(model.parameters, lr=lr_per_minibatch)], [progress_printer])
print("After Trainer")
```

The following script is printing only `"Before Trainer"` message and after that the code stops the execution. The code below the C.Trainer class instantiation don't run and the script stops. Here is the result of the whole script:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Later edit: I tried to run in Debug Mode and the following line of code produce the problem. I don't get any error, but I get the following message: Process finished with exit code -1066598274 (0xC06D007E). [Screen of Debug Mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocq5e.png) Thank you!

Later edit: Actually I see that nothing works. [The following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN6Cd.png), is showing [the following answer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZyNJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass a loss function and learner to the trainer class. Maybe you might want to take a look [here](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/Manual_How_to_feed_data.html#B.2-Feeding-data-with-full-control-over-each-minibatch-update) for some example code.

EDIT: Based on your update, you should uninstall and install again.

EDIT2: Getting intel mkl-dnn installed (use conda) with solved you probably.

Comment: I did not provide the entire code. I tried to run this [example](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/CNTK_201B_CIFAR-10_ImageHandsOn.html). But at Training and Evaluation steps, at the line `trainer = C.Trainer(z, (ce, pe), [learner], [progress_printer])
` the code stops working, as the image above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should pose your code. If everything was done correctly, it will work. check if model.shape prints out anything too while you are at it.

Comment: I have added some details in the above section.

Comment: Looks like you should do a re-installation

Comment: Hello. I had to install MKL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-mkl-on-windows) and also MKL-DNN - ```conda install -c intel mkl-dnn```. Now it is working. Thank you a lot!